# Store UIColor in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicolor

I have a UIColor created by `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:...];` and I want to store it in an NSArray.

I have a problem, however, as I have the following code for *normal* colors

```
NSString *NSStringFromUIColor(UIColor *color) {
    //Creates a string with RGB values of the color
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%f, %f, %f, %f]",
            components[0],
            components[1],
            components[2],
            components[3]];
}
```

But the above crashes with my unconventional patternColorFromImage.
So once again, how do I store this color in an NSArray etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSArray works with Objective-C objects, which the "`(float)`" cast I see up there most definitely is not.

To be more specific, "`float`", "`int`", "`char`" are [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), CGFloat is a Core Graphics data structure (and also not an Objective C object).

If you want to save colors in an array, they need to be true "`UIColor`" Objective-C objects.

If you want to save your CGFloats in a NSArray, [you can do the answer in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204958/how-do-i-make-an-array-of-cgfloats-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save parameterized colors in an array, wrap the values in NSNumbers (though, UIColor seems like a better alternative).  In other words, either

```
CGFloat red = 0.5;
NSArray *colorParams = @[ [NSNumber numberWithFloat:red], // etc
```

or, better:

```
NSArray *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red // etc
```

Either of these objects can be placed in another array:

```
NSArray *myArrayOfColors = @[ colorParams, color, // but watch out, we have two distinct
// representations of colors in this array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store C types into an NSArray. You could do this:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: components[0]], [NSNumber numberWithDouble: components[1]], nil];
```

If there in fact are only two components. Here's a more generic version:

```
CGColorRef cgColor = [myColor CGColor];
NSUInteger numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(cgColor);
CGFloat const *components = CGColorGetComponents(cgColor);
NSNumber *componentObjects[numComponents];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numComponents; i++)
    componentObjects[i] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: components[i]];
NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: componentObjects count: numComponents];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* NSStringFromColor(UIColor* color) {
    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    [color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%f, %f, %f, %f"], r, g, b, a];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the expression `[UIColor redColor]`, it is obvious to see that `redColor` is a `selector`.
Also, we can convert selectors to `NSString`s and vice-versa with:

```
NSString colorSel = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(redColor));
SEL redSel = NSSelectorFromString(colorSel");
```

I'm on a windows PC right now so cannot say for sure whether it should be enclosed in `@selector()` or not. But you can try them both out to see which one is the right way.

One you get the selector from string, you can set color with:

```
if ([UIColor respondsToSelector:redSel])
    yourElement.backgroundColor = [UIColor performSelector:redSel];
```

This is a basic example with basic `UIColor`s. You can use `UIColorFromRGB` macros, or `CGColor`s too.

Once you get an `NSString` with your color, you can easily store them in an array.